The correct way to handle Stripe payment success and route accordingly
I'm making an app where the user can top up their wallet amount using Stripe Checkout one time payment and am a bit confused.

Which webhook is normally used to detect payment status success? I've read some conflicting advice where some say to detect at checkout.session.completed, while I read that payment is not 100% confirmed as success at checkout.session.completed, and to use payment.intent.success instead. I will need to update the user's wallet balance upon success so it has to be 100%.

After topping up and Stripe routes to the success url, ideally the user will then be routed to a payment confirmation page on my app. How can I get details about the payment in this case? I read that it's possible to add a query parameter in the success url that has the session id, but it doesn't seem like a safe choice as the user can change the url if they wanted to. I was wondering what the normal way would be?


Thanks a lot!


Which webhook is normally used to detect payment status success? I've read some conflicting advice where some say to detect at checkout.session.completed, while I read that payment is not 100% confirmed as success at checkout.session.completed, and to use payment.intent.success instead. I will need to update the user's wallet balance upon success so it has to be 100%.

I'd recommend checking this guide on checking the payment outcome made on Checkout Session. To put it simply, you will check the payment_status property in the Checkout Session in any checkout.session.* event including both synchronous and asynchronous payment methods.

After topping up and Stripe routes to the success url, ideally the user will then be routed to a payment confirmation page on my app. How can I get details about the payment in this case? I read that it's possible to add a query parameter in the success url that has the session id, but it doesn't seem like a safe choice as the user can change the url if they wanted to. I was wondering what the normal way would be?

The query parameter will only contain the Checkout Session ID (cs_xxx) which your system should retrieve information that you're looking for. Alternatively, you can use the checkout.session.* event to check the payment information that suggested in the guide in the previous question.
